# KSQLDB Cluster Failure when on Multiple Bare Metal machines running docker

Tags: docker, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am getting a failure trying to join a KSQLDB cluster and serve requests. I made an image that explains the issue better than I can write it. Box titled "Cluster Fails" is my issue.

Funny part is that it definitely attempts to cluster because I get `{"@type":"statement_error","error_code":40001,"message":"Unable to execute pull query:`  when I make a call to 192.168.150.125:8087

[image]

@Robin Moffatt
So for version of KDQLDB it is the latest the docker image used is

```
image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server
```

As for log on 192.168.150.125 docker image I look at

> root@192.168.150.125:~/docker/images/ksqldb# docker logs 0ea930c887f8
> ===> Configuring ksqlDB...
> ===> Launching ksqlDB Server...
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in >version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
> [2020-06-22 14:38:07,797] INFO KsqlConfig values:
> ksql.access.validator.enable = auto
> ksql.any.key.name.enabled = false
> ksql.authorization.cache.expiry.time.secs = 30
> ksql.authorization.cache.max.entries = 10000
> ksql.connect.url = http://localhost:8083
> ksql.connect.worker.config =
> ksql.extension.dir = ext
> ksql.hidden.topics = [_confluent.*, __confl.........

No error shows at all in the docker logs [imageid] logfile. I have gone thru it from start to finish and even while attempting the query but nothing in the log telling something like "I CANNOT CONNECT OR JOIN THE CLUSTER" or even "I HAVE TRIED TO JOIN THE CLUSTER". I would have thought since this container is trying to joining a cluster there would be some kind of logging about it but nothing.

The error I get is when attempting the same query on all three servers. The first two servers run perfect as shown below but the container on different machine gets the "Unable to execute pull query:" error.

> root@192.168.150.124:~/docker/images/ksqldb# curl -X "POST" "http://192.168.150.124:8085/query" -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.ksql.v1+json; charset=utf-8" -d $'{ "ksql": "SELECT * FROM chart_usage_table WHERE ROWKEY='73bd8a1d-5a9e-4343-b0e3-878ab5c37529|+|zn|+|09066437|+|2020-05-03';", "streamsProperties": {} }'
> [{"header":{"queryId":"query_1592830554884","schema":"`ROWKEY` STRING KEY, `USERID` STRING, `ENTITYTYPE` STRING, `ENTITYID` STRING, `DATESEARCHED` STRING, `COUNT` BIGINT"}},
> {"row":{"columns":["73bd8a1d-5a9e-4343-b0e3-878ab5c37529|+|zn|+|09066437|+|2020-05-03","73bd8a1d-5a9e-4343-b0e3-878ab5c37529","pzn","09066437","2020-05-03",100]}}]
>
> root@192.168.150.124:~/docker/images/ksqldb# curl -X "POST"
> "http://192.168.150.124:8086/query" -H "Content-Type:
> application/vnd.ksql.v1+json; charset=utf-8" -d $'{ "ksql": "SELECT *
> FROM chart_usage_table WHERE
> ROWKEY='73bd8a1d-5a9e-4343-b0e3-878ab5c37529|+|zn|+|09066437|+|2020-05-03';",
> "streamsProperties": {} }'
> [{"header":{"queryId":"query_1592830563312","schema":"`ROWKEY` STRING
> KEY, `USERID` STRING, `ENTITYTYPE` STRING, `ENTITYID` STRING,
> `DATESEARCHED` STRING, `COUNT` BIGINT"}},
> {"row":{"columns":["73bd8a1d-5a9e-4343-b0e3-878ab5c37529|+|zn|+|09066437|+|2020-05-03","73bd8a1d-5a9e-4343-b0e3-878ab5c37529","pzn","09066437","2020-05-03",100]}}]
>
> root@192.168.150.124:~/docker/images/ksqldb# curl -X "POST"
> "http://192.168.150.125:8087/query" -H "Content-Type:
> application/vnd.ksql.v1+json; charset=utf-8" -d $'{ "ksql": "SELECT *
> FROM chart_usage_table WHERE
> ROWKEY='73bd8a1d-5a9e-4343-b0e3-878ab5c37529|+|zn|+|09066437|+|2020-05-03';",
> "streamsProperties": {} }'
> ***{"@type":"statement_error","error_code":40001,"message":"Unable to
> execute pull query: SELECT * FROM chart_usage_table WHERE
> ROWKEY='73bd8a1d-5a9e-4343-b0e3-878ab5c37529|+|zn|+|09066437|+|2020-05-03';","stackTrace":[],"statementText":"SELECT * FROM chart_usage_table WHERE ROWKEY='73bd8a1d-5a9e-4343-b0e3-878ab5c37529|+|zn|+|09066437|+|2020-05-03';","entities":[]}***

@Andrew Coates,

Thanks for the clarification but I am even more confused since the documentation speaks of Joining Clusters, but that is not important. The issue here is that even if I try your solution it does not work. I keep getting a binding exception which seems correct to me since a Container cannot bind anything for its Host. I am also not a Docker expert but my knuckles are bloody enough to say that the issue seems to be KSQLDB not being able to resolve something but no indication as to what it is.

```
ports:
    - "8087:8088"

extra_hosts:
    - "ACCL-FFM-SRV-125:192.168.150.125"
    - "ACCL-FFM-SRV-124:192.168.150.124"

environment:
    KSQL_LISTENERS: http://ACCL-FFM-SRV-125:8088

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
```

Here another thing though, I call a netcat server on the other machines container with no problem. So i know that network resolving is working fine from container on one machine to another container on a different machine.

```
[root@ksqldbservermvcu1 ~]# curl -X "POST" "http://ACCL-FFM-SRV-125:8086/query" 
-d $'NETCAT on container will receive this.'
```

and in the container netcat is setup to receive.

```
[root@ksqldbservermvcu4 ~]# nc -l -p 8086  
POST /query HTTP/1.1  
Host: ACCL-FFM-SRV-124:8086  
User-Agent: curl/7.61.1 Accept: */*
Content-Length: 38  
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

NETCAT on container will receive this.
```

By the way trying to use
KSQL_ADVERTISED_LISTENER: http://192.168.150.125:8088
does not get respected in any way. Notice the 's'

```
root@ksqldbservermvcu4:~/docker/images/ksqldb# docker logs a746f993b9d9 | grep advertised
    ksql.advertised.listener = null
[2020-07-02 10:44:52,127] WARN The configuration 'advertised.listener' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:355)

root@ksqldbservermvcu4:~/docker/images/ksqldb# docker logs 61fa63d920a3 | grep advertised
    ksql.advertised.listener = null
[2020-07-02 11:12:18,298] WARN The configuration 'advertised.listeners' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:355)
```

Maybe I am missing something, please help.

Comment: Can you edit your question to specify any errors in the ksqlDB server log, and also the version that you're using

Comment: It would be `KSQL_KSQL_ADVERTISED_LISTENER`, rather than `KSQL_ADVERTISED_LISTENER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can confirm that I finally got this working with the configuration shown below in my docker-compose file. But another thing I had to do was reboot the machine (this machine was not rebooted for almost a year). Also I had to delete all the topics in the Kafka Cluster. All this combined cleared the way to get this working. Hope it helps someone.

```
ksqldb-server-mvcu1:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server
    hostname: ksqldbservermvcu1
    container_name: ksqldbservermvcu1
    volumes:
        - /root/docker/images/ksqldb/docker_mapped_folders/ksqldb:/tmp/ksqldb
    ports:
        - "8087:8088"
        - "31095:31099"
    extra_hosts:
        - "ACCL-FFM-SRV-125:192.168.150.125"
        - "ACCL-FFM-SRV-124:192.168.150.124"
    environment:
        KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088
        KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 192.168.150.156:9092,192.168.150.145:9092,192.168.150.160:9092
        KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
        KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
        KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID: "ksqldb_msg_shown_cluster"
        KSQL_KSQL_ADVERTISED_LISTENER: http://192.168.150.125:8087
```

BTW: take a look at this link from Robin Moffatt for a great listener explanation
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 0):

Before pull queries were introduced, ksqlDB nodes did not talk to each other. The 'clustering' of ksqlNodes leveraged a shared command topic and the Kafka consumer groups protocol of Kafka to share out work.  This is why you're not seeing any messages about trying to join the cluster: the node doesn't join the cluster.

Pull queries using Kafka Streams' *interactive queries* under the hood. This works by each ksqlDB node advertising an endpoint other nodes can reach it. These advertised endpoints are shared between ksqlDB nodes using the Kafka consumer group protocol, i.e. the nodes become aware of each other through their communication with Kafka.

When you issue a pull query to a node that doesn't host the information you require it will attempt to forward the request to the node that does by contacting it on the endpoint it advertised. In your case, what is happening is that the endpoint your nodes from one machine are advertising is not accessible from the other machine.

KsqlDB v0.8 - 0.9 takes the first listener in the `listeners` config and uses this as its advertised listener / endpoint. A common problem is people use a wildcard or loopback address in their listener config, e.g.

```
listeners=localhost:8088
# or
listeners=127.0.0.1:8088
```

With the problem being that a ksqlDB Node running on another machine can't reach this node using these addresses.

You can likely resolve your problem by updating your `listeners` config to use the externally accessible name of the machine you're running it on. e.g.

```
listeners=my.machine.name:8088
```

Alternatively, KsqlDB also has a [`ksql.advertised.listener`](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/docs/operate-and-deploy/installation/server-config/config-reference.md#ksqladvertisedlistener) which does not itself cause ksqlDB to create another listener, but rather allows you to set the listener shared with the other nodes to something they can resolve, e.g.

```
listeners=localhost:8088
ksql.advertised.listener=host.that.all.nodes.can.resolve:8088
```

I've not tried to configure a docker image this way myself, and I'm no docker expert, but one or both of these should allow you to configure ksqlDB so that the advertised listener is resolvable and accessible from all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Andrew please see update above to original question.